# Selenium - find article by h1 and p text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to find article on website by h1 and p text like on image below?

I tried this, where I can found all articles and I don't know how to find this one with text in h1 and by text in p. And then I would like to click on this.

```
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/div[contains(@class,'inner-article')]/h1")
```

[image]

Comment: What would you like to do then? if you want to extract stuff from it, you might need some scraping library, if you'd like to click, please specify what

Comment: @Timeler I would to click on this.

Comment: Could you show us the specific url?

Comment: yes the url please, and would you like to click on the beanie custom first or the Red?

Comment: @Timeler I tried this on html editor www.w3schools.com.

Comment: @Filip cant seem to find it, where on the website is that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/div[contains(@class,'inner-article')][h1/a[contains(text(),"Beanie")]][p/a[contains(text(),"Red")]]")
```

you can use above xpath, which will check whehter the parent element article/div has child elements h1/a and p/a with texts Beanie and Red respectively

in w3chool html editor is inside iframe so switch to iframe in your seelnium tests before tryng to find the element

Answer (score 2):

To extract and print the text *Beanie Custom First* and *Red* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  - Printing *Beanie Custom First*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article.inner-article h1 > a.name-link[href='/shop/asd']"))).text)
    ```
  - Printing *Red*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article.inner-article p > a.name-link[href='/shop/asd']"))).text)
    ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  - Printing *Beanie Custom First*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//article[@class='inner-article']//h1/a[@class='name-link' and @href='/shop/asd']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - Printing *Red*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//article[@class='inner-article']//p/a[@class='name-link' and @href='/shop/asd']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)